# How to place "Description" field in List under the field name itself?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-list

In my Office 365 (SharePoint Online) I have a very simple Custom List which has a few columns/fields, and I added some description to add clarity to users. The problem is that the description's text gets added on the right-side underneath. Also,The company are not allowing using InfoPath nor any third-party solution. So, My only options are: SharePoint Designer & JavaScript.

Is there any way in SharePoint Designer or JavaScript to move the "Description" field under its column's text itself? Something like the screenshot below:

[image]

Could you please guide me how to accomplish this?

I would sincerely appreciate any help in this, Please !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works on Classic Forms where the layout is a TABLE

Once the page is created you execute JavaScript to move the DOM elements in the second TD column containing the description to the first TD column

[image]

1. Find Field by definition in `<!-- comment -->`
2. Find description by `ms-metadata`
3. move (appendChild) Node to first Column (first TD after TR)
4. add a BR so the description is below the Fieldname

> Allmost all answers/blogs will take you on a jQuery adventure for Step
>   1.   Finding the TD with `input` fields, then parsing innerHTML to find that (green) String

The [native JavaScript TreeWalker API/class/Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974360(v=vs.85).aspx) can get the Comments node with one call.
(*IE9 was the last Browser to finally support this*)

> The jQuery lovers will then do String magic to get the data from that
>   green string comment.

One `eval` statement can turn that comment into 3 variables.

#### Solution

So the only native JavaScript you have to use
(*from a Content Editor WebPart **below** your Form, so it executes **after** the Form is displayed*)

is:

```
var formCSI = new function (form){
function getComments(element) {
    function acceptNode() {     // IE *requires* this argument where other browsers don't.
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }

    var safeFilter = acceptNode;// IE *requires* this argument where other browsers don't.
    safeFilter.acceptNode = acceptNode;
    return document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, safeFilter, false);
}

  var tree=getComments(form);
  while (node=tree.nextNode()) {//loop all found <!-- comments -->
    eval(node.nodeValue.replace(/ Field/g, ';var CSI_') + ';');//convert comment to vars
    console.info(CSI_InternalName,CSI_Type,CSI_Name);
    var TD=node.parentNode;//column with input field
    var TR=node;while (TR.tagName !== 'TR') TR = TR.parentNode;//find parent TR row
    this[CSI_InternalName]=TR;// store TR as formCSI.[internalName] eg. formCSI.Title
    var desc=TD.getElementsByClassName('ms-metadata')[0];//find description span
    if(desc){
      console.info('Move Description','\n',desc,'\n',TR.firstElementChild);
      TR.firstElementChild.appendChild(desc);//move description to first Column
      desc.insertBefore(document.createElement('BR'),desc.firstChild);//add BR before desc
    }
  }
  return this;//return formCSI as object
}(document.querySelector('.ms-formtable'));//IIFE execute function immediatly

//formCSI now is an object referencing all Form Row TR elements
formCSI.Title.style.background='pink';
formCSI.AssignedTo.style.display='none';// 'table-row' to show again
```

You can delete half the lines,
I left them in to show how easy Form manipulation without jQuery is.

*Since native javascript .appendChild() actually **moves** elements, you could move any whole Field into any other HTML layout...*

iForm