# New item entry form: how to hide 2 fields with a code in SP designer NewForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, newform

I need to hide 2 fields from NewForm.aspx (the edit and view can stay the same). I have seen around tutorials on how to do it with Infopath and linking it to the permission of the user and I would like to avoid it. Is there a simple code to add to the file? Please also state where to place the eventual code.

Comment: One of the way to hide fields from new item form  is using CSR (Client Side Rendering). Please refer this link to hide fields from new item form using CSR. link --> http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168898/csr-hide-a-field-on-form-but-not-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

You can  hide theses fields  via Jquery without using SharePoint Designer by doing the following:

- Open your new form via the browser.
- Edit Page .

[image]

- Add web Part > Add Script Editor .

[image]

Add the following code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection

$('nobr:contains("Field1")').closest('tr').hide();

$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').hide();
});

</script>
```

- Replace Field1 ,Field2 with your fields name

If you need to hide fields based on choice field check [Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)

See also [Show / Hide fields based on a dropdown selection using SPUtility.js](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

Comment: Will this hide the field/column only from the entry form (NewForm) or also from the view of the list?

Comment: only from the new form

Comment: if my field1 is called with 2 words ("additional comments"), how do I type it in that line?

Comment: $('nobr:contains("additional comments")').closest('tr').hide();

Comment: Word of warning, the NOBR tag used is deprecated HTML syntax, Microsoft will probably continue support because they have used it so much, Other browsers could drop support without notice. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Answer (score 2):

- jQuery solutions are *so 2016*... since IE9 everything can be done as easily with JavaScript
- When you do not have to support pre IE9 browsers you can use vanilla JavaScript
  You have to copy/paste 5 more lines of code compared to the jQuery approach,
  but you do not have to worry about loading a 90KB jQuery library.

This only works on Classic Forms where the layout is a TABLE

Once the page is created you execute JavaScript to hide the TR displaying the Field

[image]

1. Find Field by definition in (green) `<!-- comment -->`
2. 'walk up the DOM' to its TR
3. Hide that TR

The [native JavaScript TreeWalker API/class/Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974360(v=vs.85).aspx) can get the Comments node with one call.
(*IE9 was the last Browser to finally support this*)

One `eval` statement can turn that comment into 3 JavaScript variables.

#### Solution

So the only native JavaScript you have to use
(*Paste into the NewForm.aspx or in a Script OR Content Editor WebPart **below** your Form, so it executes **after** the Form is displayed*)

is:

```
var formCSI = function (form){

function getComments(element) {
    function acceptNode() {     // IE *requires* this argument where other browsers don't.
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }

    var safeFilter = acceptNode;// IE *requires* this argument where other browsers don't.
    safeFilter.acceptNode = acceptNode;
    return document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, safeFilter, false);
}

  var tree=getComments(form);
  while (node=tree.nextNode()) {//loop all found <!-- comments -->
    eval(node.nodeValue.replace(/ Field/g, ';var CSI_') + ';');//convert comment to vars
    console.info(CSI_InternalName,CSI_Type,CSI_Name);
    var TR=node;while (TR.tagName !== 'TR') TR = TR.parentNode;//find parent TR row
    this[CSI_InternalName]=TR;// store TR as formCSI.[internalName] eg. formCSI.Title
  }
  return this;//return formCSI as object
}(document.querySelector('.ms-formtable'));//IIFE execute function immediatly

//formCSI now is an object referencing all Form Row TR elements
formCSI.Title.style.background='pink';
formCSI.AssignedTo.style.display='none';// 'table-row' to show again
```

This turns **every Field in the Form** into a JavaScript formCSI Object which you can use to color, hide, whatever you want to do with the TR rows

Also used in:

- [How to place "Description" field in List under the field name itself?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203376/how-to-place-description-field-in-list-under-the-field-name-itself)