# Full Stops are breaking my JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using M.Qassas' "Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in `SharePoint 2013`" and I've stumbled across an issue. When my `Titles` have a Full Stop (.) in them the script will not work as wanted. I'll attach my code below. Has anyone else had this experience before and a work around for it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.ms-metadata').each(function(i,obj){var dest = jQuery(obj).parents('tr:first').find('td.ms-formlabel'); jQuery(dest).append('<br>');jQuery(obj).appendTo(dest);})
jQuery('.ms-formlabel').css({'white-space':'normal'});
//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection
$("select[title='2.18 Private Sector Interest']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='2.18 Private Sector Interest']").val() != "Yes")
{
$('nobr:contains("2.18a Details of Private Sector Interest")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("2.18a Details of Private Sector Interest")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: "." will be considered as a CSS class name in jQuery selectors so you might need to change them with empty string

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Sorry for asking what is probably a very basic question but what do you mean by empty string?

Comment: As Danny answered, escape the notation will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selector doesn't work with CSS selector notation

```
$("select[title='218.Private.Sector.Interest']")
```

Fails

You can escape the notation:

```
$("select[title='218\\.Private\\.Sector\\.Interest']")
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

or use partial matching:

```
$("select[title*='218'][title*='Private']")
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

---

**Note:** You can show/hide/color Form fields without using jQuery, with vanilla JavaScript:

[How to display and hide columns on Display form based on whether they have data or not](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211809/how-to-display-and-hide-columns-on-display-form-based-on-whether-they-have-data)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding you but I've tried $("select[title='2\\.18 Private Sector Interest']") to no luck - I've updated the example above to the code that's currently not working.