# Adding help text to a OOB sharepoint text field in New form using JSLink

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, jslink

I need to add `helptext` to OOB sharepoint `Title`(text) field similar to `Sukunimi` field shown below, I have explored that JsLink to customize the `Title` field can be used for the `New` form.

how can i append my `helptext` to already rendered text box as Sharepoint is doing some id generation & mapping so that value entered in the text box are mapped to title field at the time of submission.

if i try to get the table element with the text box using JS and append my help text related html and return final html, i am not getting expected result(i see only helptext not text box).

Looks like some post processing of html was done to generate text box in ideal scenario, but as i hacked the html and put it back with appended helptext it was stopped.

Anyone aware of such post processing or how to tackle this with JSLink or javascript?

[image: Trying to add some helptext to Title Field similar to Sukunimi Field]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the existing SP Description field and relocate it under the Text field using vanilla JavaScript

Asked before here on StackOverflow

[How to place "Description" field in List under the field name itself?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203376/how-to-place-description-field-in-list-under-the-field-name-itself)

Comment: while saying we are using OOB title field for some reasons we can not change/utilize fields of `Title` and default behaviour would be used on all lists, that is why we are looking to change the behaviour at only some lists using JSLink or similar.