# Missing Comments in SP 2013 Forms

Tags: 2013, form

I had implemented a little jquery framework once, to beautify some SharePoint 2013 forms and add some customization (disabling, hiding etc).

To identify the fields and the field type, I use some standard html comments I found in the forms:

```
<!-- FieldName="URL"
         FieldInternalName="URL"
         FieldType="SPFieldURL"
      -->
```

Now I work on a (customer) machine where these comments are simply not there (same SP patch level here)... Is there a (site) feature or some setting in Central Administration that could have this site effect?

I tried a couple of different SP farms with different patch levels (including SharePoint Online) and I couldn't reproduce this issue?

-thx

Comment: You have me worried,, as I use the same technique, just not with jQuery, but with faster and more powerful [native javascript](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203376/how-to-place-description-field-in-list-under-the-field-name-itself/203413#203413). Are they not there on a standard Task List? What if you create a new Task List? What if you try a new List in another Web, and in another Site Collection?

Comment: I thought so too, that it is standard. I'm still not sure if this is a custom change of our customer, or if it is some SharePoint related propblem.

Comment: They could have created their own HTML file (and named it ASPX so SP executes it).. maybe used the HTML from an OOTB one and cleaned up. If you compare them in  Diff Editor they should hardly match. That means someone got its hands on that env. If you create a Blank Site Collection I am pretty sure (or hopeful?) the Forms will include the familair comment structure... if not... *Houston we h....* [beeeeep]....